# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CLASSNAME error already tried require_once()

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I'm coming from Java programming and I'm trying to apply my knowledge in OOP style programming in PHP.

So, I tried to create a utility class to connect to database just like how I usually do it in Java where I create a static method to get the database connection.

However, after spending hours I still can't fix the error.

**DBHelper.php**

```
<?php

class DBHelper
{
    protected $db_name = 'myDb';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = '';
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';

    public function obtainConnection()
    {

        $mysqli_instance = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
        return $mysqli_instance;
    }
}
?>
```

There are no errors in this file

Then I tried to use it on another file called `login.php`

**login.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include "/DBUtility/DBHelper.php";
    $username = $_POST['username']; //s means string
    $password = $_POST['password']; // s means string
    echo "<br/> Username value: " . $username;
    echo "<br />Password value: " . $password;
}

if (empty($username) || empty($password) ) {
    echo "Fill out the fields!";
} else {

    //PREPARE THE PreparedStatment or Stored Procedure


    $dbHelper = new DBHelper();
    $connection = $dbHelper->obtainConnection();
    $preparedStatement = $connection->prepare('CALL getUserRoleByLogin(?, ?)'); //getUserRoleByLogin() is the name of stored proc in mysql db
    $preparedStatement->bind_param('ss', $username, $password); //assign arguments to ? ?
    $preparedStatement->execute();//execute the stored procedure. This will return a result

    $userRole = $preparedStatement->store_result();
    $countOfRows = $preparedStatement->num_rows;

?>
```

I read every related question about the `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class CLASSNAME` error. I tried following the instructions given by many which is to use `require_once("DBHelper.php");` instead of `include("DBHelper.php");`
but still can't get rid of the error.

I tried making the `obtainConnection()` static and called it via `DBHelper::obtainConnection();` but with no luck. Same error message.

I get the error on opening brace of `class DBHelper` `{`

I hope you can help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, you are right to do the `require_once` or `include_once`. Does it say you can not redclare "DBHelper" or what is the class name?

Comment: @Rasclatt First, thanks. Yes, I get the error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class DBHelper

Comment: Other reasons for this could be 1) You are using the same name as a class already created somewhere else (perhaps by someone else), in that case you should be using namespaces 2) Perhaps you duplicated this file in order to rename and extend it and forgot to change the class name on the duplicate file.

Comment: Also, if you are just doing PHP new, I would suggest using `PDO` instead of `mysqli_`, though it is a personal preference, I think you will find it easier to bind values and just easier in general. You can throw an array right into your `execute()` like `$preparedStatement->execute(array(":0"=>$username,":1"=>$password));` I find PDO much easier to automate and use, but like I say, it's personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple tips you should do when doing OOP in PHP:

1) I would maybe rethink about not baking the db credentials into your class directly, it makes it harder/more cumbersome to modify them via UI if you wanted to implement a UI control mechanism down the line. Instead, try making a [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) or maybe a `json` pref file or a dynamically-created `php` file that contains an array, something like that. I will do a define because it's the easiest to demonstrate:

**/config.php**

```
# You can create a series of defines including the database
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','dbname');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS','dbpassword');
# To maximize compatibility it's helpful to define fwd/back slash
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
# It is helpful to create path defines for easy file inclusion
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('CLASSES',ROOT_DIR.DS.'classes');

# Start session
session_start();
```

2) Create a class [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) in the `config.php` file which then allows you to not have to manually include/require classes in pages. It will automatically include them:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if(class_exists($class))
        return;

    # This will turn a namespace/class into a path so should turn:
    # $db = new \DBUtility\DBHelper();
    # into:
    # /var/www/domain/httpdocs/classes/DBUtility/DBHelper.php
    $path = str_replace(DS.DS,DS,CLASSES.DS.str_replace('\\',DS,$class).'.php');
    # If the class file is located in the class folder, it will include it
    if(is_file($path))
        include_once($path);
});
```

3) I am going to create a static connection so you don't create a new connection every time (also I will use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)):

**/classes/DBUtility/DBHelper.php**

```
<?php
namespace DBUtility;

class DBHelper
{
    protected $query;
    private static $con;

    public function connection()
    {
        # This will send back the connection without making a new one
        if(self::$con instanceof \PDO)
            return self::$con;
        # I like to catch any pdo exceptions on connection, just incase.
        try {
            # Assign the connection
            self::$con = new \PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        }
        catch(\PDOException $e) {
            # Here you can just die with a more user-friendly error.
            # It would be helpful to save the actual error to a log file
            $msg = $e->getMessage();
            # I would put your log outside the root or in a protected folder
            $txt = realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.'..').DS.'errors'.DS.'sql.txt';
            # Make a directory if none set
            if(!is_dir(pathinfo($txt,PATHINFO_DIRNAME))) {
                # Make the directory
                if(mkdir(pathinfo($txt,PATHINFO_DIRNAME),0744,true)) {
                    # Save to log file
                    file_put_contents($txt,$msg.PHP_EOL);
                }
            }
            else {
                # Save to log file
                file_put_contents($txt,$msg.PHP_EOL);
            }

            die("Site is under maintenance.");
        }
    }
    # It would be helpful to create a query that will bind and not bind
    public function query($sql,$bind = false)
        {
            if(is_array($bind)) {
                foreach($bind as $key => $value) {
                    $sKey = ":{$key}";
                    $bindArr[$sKey] = $value;
                }

                $this->query = $this->connection()->prepare($sql);
                $this->query->execute($bindArr);
            }
            else {
                # The second "query" on this is the method from PDO, not the
                # "query" method from this class
                $this->query = $this->connection()->query($sql);
            }

            return $this;
        }

    public function getResults()
        {
            if(empty($this->query))
                return false;

            while($result = $this->query->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $row[] = $result;
            }

            return (isset($row))? $row : false;
        }
}
# If your page ends with a php tag, you should just remove it. It will
# protect against empty spaces that may cause "header already sent" errors
```

3a) I use something similar to this to autoload functions:

**/classes/Helper.php**

```
class Helper
    {
        public static function autoload($function)
            {
                if(function_exists($function))
                    return;

                $path = ROOT_DIR.DS.'functions'.DS.$function.'.php';
                if(is_file($path))
                    include_once($path);
            }
    }
```

4) Create useful/reusable functions or class/methods

**/functions/getUserRole.php**

```
function getUserRole($username,$password,\DBUtility\DBHelper $DBHelper)
    {
        return $DBHelper->query('CALL getUserRoleByLogin(:0, :1)',array($username,$password))->getResults();
    }
```

**/index.php**

```
# Include the config file
require_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    # No need for this line ->> include "/DBUtility/DBHelper.php";
    # Use trim to remove empty spaces on the left and right
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
}

if (empty($username) || empty($password) ) {
    echo "Fill out the fields!";
} else {
    # User our function autoloader to include this function
    Helper::autoload('getUserRole');
    # Use the function and inject the DB class
    $userRoles = getUserRole($username,$password,new \DBUtility\DBHelper());
    $count     = count($userRoles);

    echo "Count: {$count}";
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($userRoles);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. All these are gonna be useful in the future as I continue to learn the OOP way of programming in PHP. You are actually correct, I had to use a namespace together with require_once to fix the error. I'm going to study the example you've given. Most of the OOP patterns and style is similar with how I do it in Java. There are just some keyword and commands I need to learn. Thanks, again. My problem was solved by using namespace.

Comment: Hopefully some of this stuff is helpful, I added a couple extra pieces, I noticed I didn't address a couple things very well, or at all, in some cases. Cheers