# Problems when including a PHP class into an included PHP file that is called by Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, class, subclass

My live setup is as follows:

- I have an Ajax call to a PHP file ("ajax.php") on a server which I have been using and it works fine.
- The php file is now for the first time instructed to include a second PHP class within one of its functions:

  ```
  if ($stmnt) {
      require_once('path/to/statement.class.php');
      $statement = new STATEMENT();
  }
  ```
- This second class ("statement.class.php") also includes a third class within the same folder as the second class and attempts to extend it:

  ```
  require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
  class MYPDF extends TCPDF {...}
  class STATEMENT {
      public function __construct() {...}
  }
  ```

**I have been running lots of tests on the statement class, and when I call it directly from the browser, I get no errors**. It properly includes the tcpfd class and extends it and I can work with it as expected.

**However, when using above mentioned Ajax call to instruct "ajax.php" to go as an inbetween, suddenly, the server claims that it cannot find the file "tcpfd_include.php" for inclusion** as an error within "statement.class.php" and therefore cannot instatiate or extend its class TCPDF:

I get the following error when doing a simple `require_once('tcpdf_include.php');`:

*Fatal error:  Class 'TCPDF' not found in /home/[userxyz]/public_html/[ajax.php path]/path/to/statement.class.php on line 10*

(line 10 being where I'm trying to extend the class, which means that it didn't complain about an unsuccessful include, but about an unsuccessful extension of the class that should be included by now)

if I change the inclusion to say `include('tcpdf_include.php') or die ('dead');`, I get a different error message returned to me via ajax:

*Warning:  include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/[userxyz]/public_html/[ajax.php path]/path/to/statement.class.php on line 4*

*Warning:  include(1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/[userxyz]/public_html/[ajax.php path]/path/to/statement.class.php on line 4*

*Warning:  include(): Failed opening '1' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/[userxyz]/public_html/[ajax.php path]/path/to/statement.class.php on line 4*

*Fatal error:  Class 'TCPDF' not found in /home/[userxyz]/public_html/[ajax.php path]/path/to/statement.class.php on line 10*

This now leads me to believe that the relative path somehow got screwed up, so I tried:

```
echo (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/[ajax.php path]/path/to/tcpdf_include.php')?"true":"false");
```

right above the troublesome include and it spits out *true*, even via Ajax.
But even if I change the include to read:

```
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/[ajax.php path]/path/to/tcpdf_include.php') or die ("file doesn't exist");
```

I get the same error, that the file doesn't exist, failed to open stream, blah blah.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What's in this file: tcpdf_include.php?  Also note you have misspelled the file name in the code you provided : require_once('tcpfd_include.php');

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But that problem was not in my code. The TCPDF class provides functions to create PDF files on the server (see "https://tcpdf.org")

Comment: What is `[ajax.php path]` supposed to mean? If that refers to your script _file_, then how come it is in the middle of a file system path? Can you please show the full real path, without replacing parts of it?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying it make it less complicated, not more complicated:
public_html/create/tcpdf/examples/tcpdf_include.php
is the full path
[ajax.php path] is simply supposed to mean that this is the folder where my ajax.php file is in.

Comment: imo, always use an absolute filepath. You can use relative directories in absolute filepaths.When you want to access a file in the same directory. e.g. `require_once(__DIR__ .'/path/to/statement.class.php');`. To access one directory up then do: `require_once(__DIR__ .'/../path/to/statement.class.php');`. etc. These always work as they do not use the 'current working directory'. Use `getcwd();` to see where PHP will look for relative files.

Comment: @Ryan thank you. I checked into what getcwd had to say and it put me into the "create" folder (where the ajax.php file is). But when I checked into what __DIR__ had to offer, it said we're in the /path/to folder (where the classes are). I tried stringing those into the include call as you suggested, but without luck. The error message stays the same.

Comment: You really should have an autoloader for classes. You should also have have a config file that you include with every master page that contains the absolute path based on the root of the site where the config is located.

Comment: Here is an example of both: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961881/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class-classname-error-already-tried-require-once/40963468#40963468

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally solved the problems after a few wasted hours:
It turns out that @Ryan's answer was at the gist of it the solution. However, I was searching for the problem in the wrong place.

I included B.php into A.PHP and C.PHP into B.PHP and when this didn't work, I falsely assumed that C.PHP was not included correctly into B.PHP. I didn't consider that the Class I was trying to extend in B.PHP was not actually inside C.PHP but inside D.PHP or E.PHP, since the TCPDF class did its own including with relative paths. And by trying to include the whole shebang from a directory outside the folder where C.PHP was, I caused issues with sub-inclusion within the whole TCPDF package.